# $\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}\not\cong\prod_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Claim: $\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}\not\cong\prod_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Any simple proof for this?

Answer (score 7):

One is countable, the other uncountable.

Moreover, one is free, the other isn't, but the proof is rather subtle.